# Create new color scheme for Meld

Tags: gnome, colors, meld

I want to change the hard-to-read color scheme I see for `meld` (under Ubuntu 20.10.)

(I am using meld to highlight similarities between text, rather than differences. It turns out for mostly-different text, `meld` is still brilliantly useful but very hard to read under any of the color schemes.)

I have tried editing
`/usr/share/meld/meld.css`
(as described at https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Meld/DarkThemes) and it seems to make no difference.

I have tried creating a new mode
`/usr/share/meld/styles/meld-new-mode.xml`
and that new mode shows up in Meld/Preferences, and I can select it, but my edits to the .xml still do not change the text colors in `meld`.

Answer (score 0):

###### On Ubuntu 20.04.3

- Check /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/classic.xml
- Note: Change **id**
  and **_name** attributes in XML for new color scheme

###### Or try [strace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174942/how-should-strace-be-used)

> strace meld 2>&1 | grep style | grep xml

```
stat("/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/cobalt.xml", ... 
stat("/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/xubuntu-dark.xml",
```